# There are 2 nav link with the path "/home#contactus" and "/home#about" but both the link highlighted at the same time, how to fix it

Tags: reactjs

I want to add an active link using Nav-hash-link. But it's active always when I add the route like /home/#sampleproducts& /home/#dashboard.

```
import { NavHashLink as NavLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';
        <NavLink style = {navLink} to={'/#'}>Home</NavLink>
        <NavLink style = {navLink} to={'/home/#sampleproducts'}>Sample</NavLink>
        <NavLink style = {navLink} to={'/home/#dashboard'}>Dashboard</NavLink>
```

navLink function code

```
const navLink = ({isActive}) => {
```

return{
backgroundColor:isActive ? '#B31217' : '',
color:isActive ? '#fff' : ''
}

Comment: What don't u understand? you have the answer in your question

Comment: If you asked the question "What is the same between node.js and mongodb?" the answer would be "Nothing".  Why do you think these things are the same?

Answer (score 1):

node.js is a program that allows you to run javascript code natively on a host system, where it would typically only be run in a browser. This makes it similar to other interpreted languages like python or php.

MongoDB is a database tool. If you have a lot of data that you need easily stored and accessible, you would likely look into a database tool. This is similar to sql or elasticsearch. Additionally, MongoDB can be used with almost every programming language out there, so you do not even need node.js to run it. You could have a program written in C# that stores all it's data with MongoDB.